# How to reload a page and keep the .load method Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i am using laravel and jquery to make my website, i'm using the jquery .load method to fill a div in a page:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
    $('#container').load('url');
});
```

it's working fine but it's filling the container with a form, and when i submit  the form if the validation passes everything it's ok because i don't need to show the form again, but if i want to return some errors i have to click the button again to show the form again.

Is there a way to just load the page with the .load() i allready had?

Comment: You have three choices (a) perform the validation client-side, (b) perform the validation server-side via an AJAX request/response, (c) perform the validation server-side by conventional submission of the form and, on failure, return the page complete with the form.

Comment: easy trick, put a hash on form action like <form action="#send">, then on javascript you check if be post-back, if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}